# Error 'Error:Execution failed for task' when I Generate Singed App

Tags: java, android

I'm making a Youtube video player android app ,
 but when I want to Generate Singed app and build android app , I got this eror :
 "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536"

I did generate another app before ( a calculator application ) but when I did that I don't got any problem ! why did it happen ?

Comment: Solved . thanks relative posts !

Answer (score 0):

Oh , I fix ! thank you Related Posts ! :D 
for solve that , add this code :

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

below this :

```
defaultConfig {       
       }
```